# error occuring when use command make menuconfig

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel

The error displayed in the terminal is 
  `make[1]: /bin/sh: Command not found
make[1]: *** [scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 127
make: *** [scripts_basic] Error 2`
Can anyone tell me why and how to solve it

Comment: Did you read the first line?

Comment: yup how to solve it then

Comment: Were your kernel headers built for a different architecture?  Check it using  `file scripts/basic/fixdep`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this..

sudo apt-get install patch

and then

sudo apt-get install build-essential

after this you can try your Makefile